# Choosing vacuum as the initial state of EM field in scattering-like problems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering

My question can be made clear in the context of spontaneous emission of atoms, although it appears almost everywhere in questions involving interactions between charged particles and fields. In many textbooks which discuss spontaneous emission try to compute the transition amplitude $\langle f|U(t)|i\rangle$ with the choice $|i\rangle=|e\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle$ and $|f\rangle=|g\rangle\otimes|\hbar\vec{k}\rangle$, where $|\phi\rangle$ is the vacuum state of the EM field and $|\hbar\vec{k}\rangle$ denotes the 1-photon state of the EM field.

This simple choice of states seems to be rather puzzling to me. The initial state $|i\rangle=|e\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle$ seems to suggest that before the emission, the EM field is 0 everywhere in the space. However, intuitively the particle itself should have an EM field around it, making the state of EM field somewhat less trivial than the vacuum. Even if the particle is an overall neutral particle like a hydrogen atom, it is also a composite of two particles of opposite charges, and the EM field should not be trivial at least at small distance.

I wonder whether the initial state was chosen to be $|i\rangle=|e\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle$ only in the approximate sense in terms of scattering-like problems, or whether it is actually exact yet my understanding of the EM field state is wrong.

Thanks for any response in advance.

---

To be more specific, I consider an easier case. Consider a free electron propagating in vacuum. At the first sight, it's tempting for me to choose $|\vec{p}\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle$ to describe the state. However, in classical electrodynamics, we know that the moving electron itself emits an EM field. Therefore, it seems more reasonable for me if the state is chosen to be $$|\vec{p}\rangle\otimes|f\rangle,$$ where $|f>$ is the EM field state such taht the expectation value of the field operators computed using this state $|f\rangle$ should give us the classical expression of EM field emitted by the particle.

In particular, when $p\rightarrow 0$, I expect something like
$$\langle f|\vec{E}(\vec{x},t)|f\rangle\rightarrow\frac{-e}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\hat{r}.$$

Please feel free to criticize me if this is due to any of my misunderstanding of the definition of EM field. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's particularly relevant whether the EM field is in the state $|0\rangle$ or $|n\rangle$, where $|n\rangle$ represents the Fock State with $n$ photons. The problem always decomposes into a $2\times 2$ subspace of the overall Fock space, namely $\{|g\rangle, |e\rangle\} \otimes \{|n\rangle, |n+1\rangle\}$.

Comment: Tomas Russell Thanks. I think my question is about the intuition of this subspace. $|n>$ is the state of n freely propagating photons. My idea is, since the atom is charged, or has charged components, the EM field in the space does not seem to be as trivial as $|n>$ or $|n+1>$ or any superposition of these two. For example, even there is a free electron moving in the space, classically there is an E field and a B field (Jefimenko's formula)This makes me think that the field may not be just $|n>$ state.